# Setting multiple HTML attributes to the same value

Tags: html

I have an input of type number in my form. Can I set the 'min' and 'max' attributes at once? I mean can I write something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<form action="MyWeb.asp">
Quantity (between 1 and 10): <input type="number" name="quantity"  min, max="10">
<input type="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

instead of:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<form action="MyWeb.asp">
Quantity (between 1 and 10): <input type="number" name="quantity"  min="1" max="10">
<input type="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Well no. Not in HTML. What's even the point of using a "number min: 10, max:10"? If you want to force a user to have a fixed number just use and input hidden with its value set to 10.

Comment: No, this is just not possible. HTML itself is just a markup language. In would suggest to use javascript if you are looking into doing more advanced stuff.

Comment: using the w3 schools examples, you can see that you cannot do what you ask http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_form_number_adv

Comment: While, setting `min` and `max` to the same value might make no sense. The  question _(and the answers, of course)_ itself is useful as a **"Can multiple attributes be set to same value, with single expression?"** reference. For example, cases like `<input id='name' name='name>` are not that seldom, so one might wonder  if something like `<input id=name='name>` or `<input id, name='name>` is possible — **which is not**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. HTML provides no shorthand means to set multiple attributes at once.

The closest you could come would be to use a loop in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to do that, but you can use a hidden input field to force the user to input value of 10.

```
<input hidden type="number" name="quantity" value="10">
```